# What is the easiest way to get installation error of .apk Android app?

Tags: android, apk

I'm developing an Android app which keeps track of installation status of other apps. I want to test a scenario when some app fails to install. For this I need an bad .apk file which would fail. What is the easiest way to get such a file? Maybe Google provides such test .apk's? Is there some way to easily change some apk to get it to fail?

Comment: try to install an installed app would make it fail, also try to install unsiged apk would make the same result.

Comment: Corrupted apk can be used, start building apk from android studio and stop it in between then pick apk file from output folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any '*apk' is compressed archive such as '*zip'. So, I think the easiest way to corrupt any '*apk' is to change its extension to '*zip', unpack, delete any file (or for ensure Manifest.xml), pack to '*zip' and change extension back to '*apk'.

Hope it helps